# How do I input a NodeJS variable as a parameter in a MongoDB Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've read through every stack overflow I can find and I don't understand why this still isn't working.

I'm trying to construct a NodeJS Mongo find query and very simply want to use a variable as the values, the key does not need to be dynamic.

This is the code I was working with initially :

**collection.find({project_id : project_id_val})**

but this simply returns :

**Found the following records**

**[]**

I've also tried constructing my own javascript object and passing that in e.g.

**Query = {}**

**Query["project id"] = project_id_val**

**collection.find(query)**

But that doesn't work either, I know the key/value pair is correct because 
project_id: "12345" works absolutely fine, and returns exactly what I want it to. I feel like this should be very simple so if someone could let me know where I'm going wrong that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you log out the value `project_id_val` do you get the value you are expecting? Is there a document in your database that corresponds with that value? Also, is the type of that value correct?

Comment: Is your `project_id_val` a number and your data in DB a string?

Comment: Wow! I feel stupid, it was the type, I was inserting it as an int but for some reason when I was passing it as a parameter to my get API it classed the variable as a string. I changed it to a string in the MongoDB and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @ryand88 glad you figured it out. One other thing, if it is a MongoDB Object Id, something you would see under `_id`, you should use the ObjectID type. Just wanted to point that out: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/